google authentication redirect doesn not work for me
I have python code to authenticate and authorize user to login app via google but in my code when ı click login with google , it just refreshs pages and doesn't direct me to login with google account page. I think everythink is correct in my code but ı couldn't figure it out. redirect_uri's are matched with google console , everyhing setted up properly.
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, session, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
app.secret_key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
oauth = OAuth(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)

google = oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id=app.config["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
    client_secret=app.config["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    access_token_url='https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    redirect_uri='http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback',  
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid profile email'},
)

facebook = oauth.register(
    name='facebook',
    client_id=app.config['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'],
    client_secret=app.config['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
    access_token_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
    redirect_uri='http://localhost:5000/auth/facebook/callback',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'email public_profile'},
)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/login/google')
def login_google():
    redirect_uri = url_for('auth_callback', provider='google', _external=True)
    return google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@app.route('/auth/<provider>/callback')
def auth_callback(provider):
    try:
        if provider == 'google':
            token = google.authorize_access_token()
            user_info = google.parse_id_token(token)    
        elif provider == 'facebook':
            token = facebook.authorize_access_token()
            resp = facebook.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email')
            user_info = resp.json()
        
        if user_info:
            session['user'] = user_info
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            flash('Authorization failed, try again')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    except Exception as e:
        flash(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return redirect(url_for('home'))



@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            session['user'] = {'id': user.id, 'username': user.username}
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            flash('Check username or password')
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        existing_user_by_username = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        existing_user_by_email = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        
        if existing_user_by_email:
            flash('Email in use, change email')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))

        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password, method='pbkdf2:sha256')
        new_user = User(username=username, email=email, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Successful sign up, please login')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    user = session.get('user')
    if not user:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('dashboard.html', user=user)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('user', None)
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all() 
    app.run(debug=True)


<body>
    <div class="login-container">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <a href="{{ url_for('auth_callback', provider='google') }}">Login with Google</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('auth_callback', provider='facebook') }}" class="facebook">Login with Facebook</a>
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register here</a></p>
    </div>
</body>

